# TYPO3 Media (Image) Height/Width not working

Tags: typo3

We have a page with a gallery of images. And we want to make the images smaller. When i set the width/height (https://gyazo.com/db5d58184d4ef6b55cdb98b261dc76bd) it doesn't update in the html: https://gyazo.com/e5e19accbfdb2954af8ed75820bf3c19

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the site you are working on is based on a responsive frontend template, thus ignoring any adjustments to width and height, because they would destroy the repsonsive behaviour of those images.

Usually the fields you showed in your screenshot should be made invisible in this case, but maybe someone just forgot to do so.

You should ask the company and/or integrator who built that site for you, if this is the case and to remove those fields form the editors view to avoid confusion.

Comment: Seems like a really valid reason. I said this to my boss and notified the client. The client responded with 'Before the update it worked, please fix it' Is there any way to force the image height/width?